# Remove non matching values in csv column

Tags: linux, bash, csv, awk, gsub

I need to validate and clean a field in CSV. There is column for IP address and I need to remove only invalid data inside that column.

I tried the following command :

```
awk 'BEGIN{ FS=OFS="," }{ gsub(/^([0-9]{1,3}[\.]){3}[0-9]{1,3}$/,"", $3) }1' input.csv
```

Input file

```
anna,new york,192.168.1.5,usa
james,denver,240.210.1.8,usa
peter,denver,colarado,usa
tommy,new york,10.2.8.3 male,usa
```

Current output

```
anna,new york,,usa
james,denver,,usa
peter,denver,colarado,usa
tommy,new york,10.2.8.3 male,usa
```

Expected output

```
anna,new york,192.168.1.5,usa
james,denver,240.210.1.8,usa
peter,denver,,usa
tommy,new york,10.2.8.3,usa
```

This command remove the matching data, but I need the opposite. How do I remove only the non-matching data in the IP column ?

Comment: I noticed you wrote `10.2.8.3 male` in your IP column for the input file, is this a typo ?

Comment: If this `male` is not a typo please edit your question and clearly explain how you sanitize your fields. What would you do with `1.2.3`? And `300.1.2.3`? And `1.2.3.4.5`? And `1.2.3.4 5.6.7.8`? Etc.

Comment: Define what you mean by _matching_ vs. _nonmatching_. From your examples, I would infer that a non-matching field is one which contains a non-numeric character, that is not a period. Is this correct?

Comment: In particular, is the entry `999.999.999.999` matching or non-matching?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I remove only the non-matching data in the IP column ?

You might combine following [string functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html): `match` `substr` for this task following way

```
anna,new york,192.168.1.5,usa
james,denver,240.210.1.8,usa
peter,denver,colarado,usa
tommy,new york,10.2.8.3 male,usa
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}{$3=match($3,/([0-9]{1,3}[\.]){3}[0-9]{1,3}/)?substr($3,RSTART,RLENGTH):"";print}' file.txt
```

gives output

```
anna,new york,192.168.1.5,usa
james,denver,240.210.1.8,usa
peter,denver,,usa
tommy,new york,10.2.8.3,usa
```

Explanation: I inform GNU `AWK` that `,` is both field separator (`FS`) and output field separator (`OFS`), then for each line I use so called ternary operator condition`?`valueiftrue`:`valueiffalse, condition is if `$3` does match regular expression, observe that I altered it slightly, so it does hold if IP is somewhere inside, rather than span whole column. If match found I use `substr` to get substring which does correspond to match using `RSTART`, `RLENGTH` which were set by match, otherwise I use empty string. After that I `print` whole line.

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*

Answer (score 0):

If your CSV is as simple as what you show (one line per record, no commas inside fields, no quoted fields, no leading or trailing spaces in fields...), and after removing the `male` in `10.2.8.3 male` (is it a typo?), you could try:

```bash
$ awk -F, -v OFS=, '$3 !~ /^([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}$/ {$3 = ""} {print}' input.csv
anna,new york,192.168.1.5,usa
james,denver,240.210.1.8,usa
peter,denver,,usa
tommy,new york,10.2.8.3,usa
```

And if you want to check that the 3rd field is really a valid full IP address (no subnets):

```bash
$ cat filter.awk
function isIP(v) {
  if(v !~ /^([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}$/)
    return 0;
  split(v, a, /\./)
  for(i = 1; i <= 4 ; i++) {
    if(a[i] > 255) {
      return 0;
    }
  }
  return 1
}
BEGIN { FS = ","; OFS = "," }
! isIP($3) {$3 = ""}
{print}

$ cat input.csv 
bob,LA,292.168.1.5,usa
anna,new york,192.168.1.5,usa
james,denver,240.210.1.8,usa
peter,denver,colarado,usa
tommy,new york,10.2.8.3,usa

$ awk -f filter.awk input.csv 
bob,LA,,usa
anna,new york,192.168.1.5,usa
james,denver,240.210.1.8,usa
peter,denver,,usa
tommy,new york,10.2.8.3,usa
```